# Will it be possible using regex to eliminate single quote in between the single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

There is a really big application, which is having the problem with single quotes sending to a database while executing a query, as of now using replace function to replace single quote with 2 single quotes which solves the issue for specific attributes, but I want to do a minimal change which can take care of the entire application issue in the DAL layer.

Here is my question :

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_procedurename ('1', 'test', 'tester's code', '0')

The above string should be converted to

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_procedurename ('1', 'test', 'tester''s code', '0') Or
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_procedurename ('1', 'test', 'testers code', '0')

either replacing with 2 single quotes or eliminating it also works.

Comment: I would REALLY recommend using parameterized queries.  This is exactly the security hole that they don't have.

Comment: Can you say if after ' always will have the character s? Like tester's code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
  string pattern = @"(\w+)'(\w+)";
  string replacement = "$1''$2";
  string input = "EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_procedurename ('1', 'test', 'tester's code', '0')";
  string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Use "$1$2" as replacement if you don't want the single quotes.

Comment: This will just work with parameters that has only words. "12 tester's code" for example won't work...

Comment: It does work, I've just tested it. \w matches digits in a string as well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong because you have way more rep than I do and probably have a much better idea of what you're talking about, but doesn't using lookahead/lookbehind have more overhead to it than a simple character pattern?

Comment: There is no lookahead/lookbehind in the `pattern = @"(\w+)'(\w+)";`; this *is* a simple character pattern. If you are really worried about performance then the second `+` could be omitted as there is no point in searching for (and replacing) multiple characters after the quote. You might also want to test the performance with and without the first `+`.

Comment: Adrian, my comment was a response to an alternative pattern someone posted using lookahead which has since been deleted. You're right that the second plus sign isn't necessary, though, good catch.

Comment: I understand @John. I did not see the (now deleted) attempt, only your answer. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks much John Clifford... it worked as I expected.